# Dashboard variable in grafana: ignore changing labels

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a dashboard in Grafana which shows Prometheus metrics for instances, where "instance" is operation system on physical or virtual server.

Number of instances is changing over time, so there is no "closed list of instances".

Dashboard detects list of instances on the fly with dashboard variable, "type" is "query", definition is `label_values(node_uname_info{job="$job"}, instance)`. It works fine while set of labels for each "instance" in metric "node_uname_info" is unchanged. But if I add new label to metric, this results in "disappearance" of the old instance and "emergence" of a new instance.

- Step 1: add instance "myhostname" as new prometheus target
- Step 2: it appears in dashboard as new instance `{instance="myhostname", job="myjob"}`
- Step 3: add label "newlabel" to existing prometheus target
- Step 4: it appears in dashboard as new instance `{instance="myhostname", job="myjob", newlabel="value"}` (instead of old one)
- Step 5: visualizations on dashboard shows metrics for "old" instance from step 2 and "new" instance from step 4 separately (with separate legends, different colors, etc.), because for Grafana these two instances are not the same [image: example of doubled visualization]

How could I change Grafana dashboard settings (I guess - settings related to dashboard variable) to completely ignore all labels, except `job` and `instance`, while detecting list of instances on the fly? So changing (or adding or removing) labels, except `job` and `instance`, will not cause in changing list of instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each timeserie is defined by set of labels. Your panel query returns 2 timeseries in this case, so Grafana shows them as 2 different instances.

Your panel query should handle it (it is not a problem. of dashboard variable) - aggregate there per job, instance as well, so only single timeserie will be a result.

Comment: "aggregate there per job, instance as well" - Is replacing `node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="$node",job="$job",device!~'rootfs'}` with `sum by (job,instance,device,mountpoint,fstype) (node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="$node",job="$job",device!~'rootfs'})` the correct implementation of your answer?

Comment: @AntonioK I don't know your datamodel, so I can just guess: yes